# Kohana 3.2 auth module and fatal error

Tags: php, web-applications, kohana-3.2

it just not serious question.
but I found something in kohana 3.2 (and I not understand)

so, I already implement authorization with Auth module 
and alway check authorization with this code.

```
//in controller
    if(Auth::instance()->get_user() == null)// not login
    {
         $this->request->redirect("authen/login"); //navigate to login page
    }
```

it working fine !!

then I try to put this code in view file. (anywhere in view file)

```
<?php $dummy->dummy()?>
```

So, this code  will make error like this

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function dummy() on a non-object
```

it look like a normal case, because $dummy is not defined

then I refresh it or navigate to other page

```
Auth::instance()->get_user() == null // it become true, after fatal error happen !! and redirect me to login page
```

My Question is 
 - **Why 'Auth::instance()->get_user()' is return null    after fatal error happen**?

Anyone share this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if user is logged in with:

```
if ( ! Auth::instance()->logged_in())
    $this->request->redirect("authen/login");
```